# CodeIgniter default database driver is mysql instead of mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, mysqli

According to php.net, mysql is deprecated and mysqli should be used instead. Why is 'dbdriver' (in application/config/database.php) set as mysql by default instead of mysqli or better yet PDO?

Comment: It was deprecated but same as for some reason a lot of businesses are stuck in XP, a lot of devs and hosts are in php4 - early php5. You can (to some degree) use CodeIgniter in an older version of PHP.

Comment: @dwhite.me so if i'm starting a new project I should change it to mysqli right? Or PDO?

Comment: I use mysqli, never had any issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can always change that to mysqli, but before changing to mysqli enable mysqli in php.ini [As described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250437/2200654).