# Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in Linode Server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cpanel, linode

My Server is Linode and when i have deployed my php application there i got `Fata error: Class 'mysqli' not found` in Linode Server i have seen and tried the steps given in following link

> [Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found)

but it did'nt solve my issue. Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Are you certain `MySQLi` is installed? I know you said the linked question didn't help but just want to make certain you've checked that.

Comment: James- Can u please tell me how can i check whether mysqli is installed or not.

Comment: If you have root access to the server, run `php -m | grep -i mysql` this will spit out installed packages that contain `mysql` if you have `mysqli` installed then it will be one of the outputs. If you don't have root access then just use `phpinfo();` to find out.

Comment: Yes i have root access and i tried it returned mysql mysqlnd pdo_mysql and returned a welcome screen.

Comment: Then you have your answer: mysqli is not installed, so install it.

Comment: i used following command sudo yum install php-mysqli to install mysqli but the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked that you have enabled it? Check your `php.ini` file for this line or something similar `extension=mysqli.so`

Answer (score 0):

MySQLi comes as part of the `php5-mysql` package and installing this will enable it by default.

As you have it installed as you've mentioned, it may just be that it isn't enabled. Check your `php.ini` for this or something along these lines; `extension=mysqli.so` . It may be commented out, or the .so file is present in your extensions directory but not linked to PHP via that extension= directive.

Source: [How to install MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250356/how-to-install-mysqli)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. but where i will find php.ini file on server.

Comment: Because i did'nt find it in public html folder

Comment: Run `php --ini` it will output where the file is located

Comment: it gives usr/local/lin/php.ini but i do not find these directories. Can i uenable mysqli from command line if yes how i can achieve it

Comment: @user3653474 Yes you can, as root `php5enmod mysqli` if you are running PHP 5.4+

Comment: @user3653474 What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96210/discussion-between-user3653474-and-james).