# Installing mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my form to the database but it keeps giving me this error.

```
( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\Excercise\Real\base.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.4390  135464  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.5110  137784  include( 'C:\wamp\www\Excercise\Real\base.php' )    ...\index.php:1
3   0.7050  138816  mysql_connect ( )   ...\base.php:9
```

Comment: So what is the question? myqsl is deprecated and removed from php 7. Then use mysqli. http://php.net/manual/it/book.mysqli.php

Comment: use `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql` functions

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that your version of mysql is outdated and you need to use mysqli instead.

Comment: Oh! ok thanks, but how will I get mysqli?

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250356/how-to-install-mysqli