# PHP 7 cannot find MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason, Windows 7 is unable to find the MySQL install. I've tried quite a few things to little or no avail.

I want to connect to my MySQL database with php using this code:

```
$con = new mysqli($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else{
    echo "<h3> Database Connected <h3>";
}
```

When I do connect, I receive this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache\htdocs\test_connection.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache\htdocs\test_connection.php on line 8

I ran this code and it returns that I don't have `mysqli` loaded:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!! ';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

I have added

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
```

and

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

to both `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`

I have my extensions in

```
C:\php\ext
```

and I also have the `php_mysqli.dll` file in that folder.

I have added the following code to the end of my httpd.exe file in Apache

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

Comment: What have your tried to do in relation to your PHP and Apache setup to resolve this? What does a test page for `phpinfo();` report?

Comment: what does phpinfo say

Comment: my extension dir is `extension_dir = "C:/Apache24/~PHP_download/php-5.6.11-Win32-VC11-x64/ext/"`

Comment: so yours would be `= "C:/php/ext/"`

Comment: It takes hours sometimes. Mine took a while due to 32 bit vs 64 bit download discrepancies. total PITA. and the slashes going the "other" way

Comment: when you are done, as I said in the first comment, have a php file with `phpinfo();` in a php block. That is it. Google phpinfo() if you need to. When it is all set and healthy after an apache (or whatever) restart, you should have a mysqli block when you scroll down looking at that rendered php file. It should have your flavor of [THIS](http://amishgourd.com/phpinfo7.php) ... scroll down about 40% to see mysqli and or pdo (when you do that beast)

Comment: @martin I don't know how removing the `mysql` tag benefits this solution right now. It is not like a `sql-server` tag on a mysql question

Comment: @Drew the tag states:  `if the issue related to MySQLi use that tag instead. `, and the MySQLi tag is present, and the code is using MySQLi and PHP7 does not support native MySQL so figured it was more concise to stick with simply the `mysqli` tag.

Comment: Some of us only filter on say `mysql`. Had it not been mysql to begin with, I would never have found this thing. We don't filter on fringe tags. You are just taking eyes off this thing that could help

Comment: Also OP specifically states using the `php_mysqli.dll ` extension. Perhaps you should search filter MySQLi as well as MySQL ?

Comment: I don't care to. I just want the guy to get eyes on his question. Perhaps I should add the PDO tag so maybe someone there can get the guy some help

Comment: When i run phpinfo(); I do not find a MySQLi block. The only instance of MySQLi in my phpinfo() is under module authors.

Comment: The mysql and mysqli block is not present in my phpinfo

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250356/how-to-install-mysqli

Comment: I have read the relevant questions already asked including that one, and found no sucess. In the linked question they seem to be doing what i have already done except the mac version.

Answer (score 6):

For me (on linux debian version) when I migrated from `php5` + `ubuntu 14` over to `php7` + `ubuntu 16`, it was:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

to

```
LoadModule php7_module /php/php7apache2_4.dll
```

and

```
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

to

```
PHPIniDir /php
```

I fought this problem for days and the answer was that simple.