# mysqli call from php running on google compute fails to connect to google cloud sql instance

Tags: php, mysqli, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have authorized my google compute VM's static ipaddress for the cloud sql instance.

I can connect to the cloud sql instance using a mysql client on my compute VM but when I am running a php script on the compute VM it fails on the mysqli create connection call with a 500 error saying cannot load resource (console error)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the whole error? What resource? Are you able to connect to any other MySQL instance?

Comment: test.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). Here is the script with the connection details changed:echo "step 200";
$conn = new mysqli("99.999.999.100", "user", "password", "DBname");
if($conn->connect_errno) {
  echo 'Database connection failed...' . 'Error: ' . $conn->connect_errno . ' ' . $conn->connect_error;
  exit;
} else {
  $conn->set_charset('utf8');
}
echo "Just after conn"; I dont see any other error being display in the browser console and I dont see the echo just after conn displayed on the plage

Comment: Can you please provide detailed php error log? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/7034621

Comment: I believe you may have mysqli misconfigured, hence I asked if you're able to connect to any other MySQL database.

Comment: I can connect to the same google cloud sql instance using a mysql client on the compute vm successfully

Comment: I'm talking about the php library, the fact you can connect with client apps rules out general connectivity issue/database instance issue.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I added the error ini in the script and here is the error it shows now Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 37

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250437/7034621

Comment: Thank you so much. I did a yum update and then an apache restart which solved this issue.